# Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro

Tags: flutter, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

@@@@@@ Here my problem:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           17.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[85761]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5dd5160) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10ca802c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[85761]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f5dd51b0) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x10ca80318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/c2/_5qtd3yx59gdmf0t6qtwzskh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.v5r2KW/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirTUqOco/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    Failed to package /Users/arnaudp/Documents/GitHub/PBSLive%20%28Flutter%29.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/arnaudp/Documents/GitHub/PBSLive%20%28Flutter%29/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
```

---

@@@@@@@ This is my flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-arm, locale en-LA)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/arnaudp/Documents/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (10 months ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/arnaudp/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0-rc1
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/arnaudp/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode13.4.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • F90C672D-5166-452D-BDDC-C36CCDF6EAF3 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-7 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.64
    ! Error: iPad is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPad is connected. (code -13)
    ! Error: iPad (2) is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPad (2) is connected. (code -13)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: have you run command : cd ios ->  pod install .. before running your project?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes I have run all